# How to count values of a column and group by range?

Tags: sequelize.js

If I have an age column in a table how can I retrieve a count of values that fall in to 5 ranges?

I have a query currently which gets only a count of users where the age is not null or undefined.

```
User.findAll({
     where: {
       age: {
         [Op.not]: null,
         [Op.notIn]: ['null', 'undefined']
       },
     },
     group: ['age', 'count'],
     attributes: [
            ['age', 'label'],
            [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('user_id')), 'count']
          ],
        })
```

current output: 
`{label: 28, count: 86}`

Desired result:

```
ages: {
 0-20: 5,
 20-40: 39,
 40-60:28,
 60-80:11,
 80-100:3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I used a literal query for this:

```
User.findAll({
          where: {
            age: {
              [Op.not]: null,
              [Op.notIn]: ['u', 'undefined', 'x', '']
            }
          },
          attributes: [
            [Sequelize.literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN age < 20 THEN age END)'), '<20'],
            [Sequelize.literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN age >= 20 AND age <= 29 THEN age END)'), '20-29'],
            [Sequelize.literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN age >= 30 AND age <= 39 THEN age END)'), '30-39'],
            [Sequelize.literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN age >= 40 AND age <= 49 THEN age END)'), '40-49'],
            [Sequelize.literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN age >= 50 THEN age END)'), '≥50'],
            [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('user_id')), 'count']
          ]
        }),
```